# Convert pandas dataframe values to float WHEN/IF POSSIBLE

Tags: pandas, dataframe

All search results show how to convert all string to float, but I need something which can change values to floats when/if it's possible to do so.

df= df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') converts strings to null, which I don't want.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `errors='ignore'` as shown in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html).

Comment: Thank you very much.